# How can I replace a charater in a text file using the cmd of windows 7?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a text file (a database) that I have imported from Internet but it containts a character that makes compilation error.

I have to change `‘TUNISIE’` with `'TUNISIE'` so I must change the charcters `‘` and `’` with a `'` in 300 lines!! Can I get any help? Please?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use notepad.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q28194558.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:‘=q!"
 SET "line=!line:’=Q!"
 ECHO(!line!
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28194558.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

Note that I made the substituted characters q`and`Q` for ease of identification where the substitutions have been made. Replace then with the characters of your choice.